# Python version of a given project

Tags: python, version

I'm a fan of Arduino projects and I came across a HID project. Things were really straightforward until i wanted to test the hardware. 
The developer uploaded an example of a Python program to test everything. It's the first time I use Python and I get error after error.
Can you please tell me what versions of software and libraries I need to install in order to run this app? I find lots of libraries that are not compatible with the version of Python, Windows x86/64 etc.

```
import sys
from pygame import *
import os
from ocempgui.widgets import *
from ocempgui.widgets.Constants import *

base.GlobalStyle.load("joy.style")

init()
j = joystick.Joystick(0)
j.init()
print 'Initialised Joystick : %s' % j.get_name()
print 'Num axes:',j.get_numaxes();
print 'Num buttons:',j.get_numbuttons();

# Grab current joystick status
event.pump()

class Application():
def event(self, evt):
    if evt.type == JOYAXISMOTION:`
```

Is this enough information or should I post the full code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should also include the errors you are getting. It could be you don't have all libraries involved (you'll need to have the pygame and ocempgui packages), or they installed incorrectly, or it didn't connect, or something else. Can you [edit] that information in?

Comment: As for Python, the grammar of the snippet you post is from the 2.x versions, so you'll need one of those, and not one of the 3.x versions.

Comment: do you have a requirements.txt file? if so you just need to create a virtual environment and in there run pip install -r requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

Please post your errors and what Python version you are using. The most likely problem is that you do not have the modules required. Wherever you see

```
import pygame
```

Which is the same thing as

```
from pygame import *
```

There are modules that Python is trying to import, but are not there on your filesystem. The first thing I would do is install pip for your version of Python and install the packages you need using the command line command:

```
pip install (insert package name here)
```

However, there are some packages that already come preinstalled like os. Again, it would really help to see your errors.

Hope this helped!
-Dave

Answer (score 0):

waw thanks for the fast responses 
i'm running everything on windows 7 x64

i had installed 
python-3.4.2 x86,
papi-0.0.9,
pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win32.whl,

and the error is

```
File "F:\Proiecte\ARDUINO\HID\Arduino UNO Big Joystick\joy.py", line 37
print 'Initialised Joystick : %s' % j.get_name()
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax    ^
```

im pretty sure i did not install something but i do not know what i need to install

and if i try to import in python GUI
i get

```
>>> import pygame  #ok
>>> import sys     #ok
>>> import os      #ok
>>> import ocempgui
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    import ocempgui
 ImportError: No module named 'ocempgui'
```

i had tried to install 
dhellmann-pymotw-3-df1d7024aba7
the requirements are

```
alabaster==0.7.6
Babel==2.1.1
cogapp==2.4
docutils==0.12
flake8==2.5.0
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
mccabe==0.3.1 
Paver==1.2.4
pep8==1.5.7
pyenchant==1.6.6
pyflakes==1.0.0
Pygments==2.0.2
pytz==2015.7
six==1.10.0
snowballstemmer==1.2.0
Sphinx==1.3.1
sphinx-rtd-theme==0.1.9
sphinxcontrib-paverutils==1.10.0
sphinxcontrib-spelling==2.1.2
wheel==0.26.0
feedparser==5.2.1
pyquery==1.2.9
python-wordpress-xmlrpc==2.2
```

and i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\HUNTER\Desktop\dhellmann-pymotw-3-df1d7024aba7\dhellmann-pymotw
-3-df1d7024aba7\pavement.py", line 6, in <module>
from paver.easy import options, Bunch, task, consume_args, sh, info, error,
cmdopts, dry
ImportError: No module named 'paver'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

are those information's enough?

Comment: Ok try to install that package, normally every time you work with python the best way is creating a Virtual Environment so all libraries you install live in that project alone, and you don't have version problems further down the road. To install a package once you are in the virtual environment you use pip install <module> as suggested in another answer

Comment: You should really edit all additional relevant information into your question instead of adding it as an answer.  Stack Overflow isn't a forum or message board, you shouldn't keep adding new posts (answers).

Answer (score 0):

hi again i had reinstall everything and now i have

```
python-2.7.11

pygame-1.9.2a0-hg_ea3b3bb8714a.win32-py2.7

OcempGUI-0.2.7
```

if i write run

```
>>>import pip # no errors
>>>import os # no errors
>>>import sys # no errors
>>>import pygame # no errors
```

when i try to run

```
>>>pip install numeric   #syntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>pip install (numeric)  #syntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

if i run setup.bat of the program i get

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "F:\Proiecte\ARDUINO\HID\Arduino UNO Big Joystick\joy.py", line 29, in <module>
 from ocempgui.widgets import *
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ocempgui\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
 import ocempgui.draw
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ocempgui\draw\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
 import Complex
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ocempgui\draw\Complex.py", line 29, in <module>
 import Numeric
 ImportError: No module named Numeric
 Press any key to continue . . .
```